# How to write a key bindings in emacs for easy repeat?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Let's say I bind the key to a certain function as follows:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c =") 'function-foo)
```

Now, I want the key binding to work as:
After I press `C-c =` for the first time, if I want to repeat the function-foo, I don't need to press `C-c` again, but simply repeat pressing `=`. Then, after I call the function-foo for enough times, I can just press keys other than `=` (or explicitly press `C-g`) to quit.

How to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `repeat` command? It is bound to `C-x z` and you may use it to repeat the previous command. It repeats that command each time you press `z`.

Comment: @mk1 i know C-x z, I just wonder if i can make my own key bindings that works in that way...anyway, thanks for your comments

Comment: `C-x e` for executing keyboard macros has the desired behavior.  If the implementation of that binding is in the elisp somewhere, that could be a start on writing your own binding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This may be the thing you are looking for:

```
(defun function-foo ()
  (interactive)
  (do-your-thing)
  (set-temporary-overlay-map
    (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
      (define-key map (kbd "=") 'function-foo)
      map)))
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a [smartrep.el](https://github.com/myuhe/smartrep.el) package that does exactly what you need. The documentation is a bit scarce but you can get a grip of how it's supposed to be used by looking into numerous emacs configs found on github. For example (taken from [here](https://github.com/shishi/.emacs.d/blob/master/inits/20-smartrep.el)):

```lisp
(require 'smartrep)
(smartrep-define-key
    global-map "C-q" '(("n" . (scroll-other-window 1))
                       ("p" . (scroll-other-window -1))
                       ("N" . 'scroll-other-window)
                       ("P" . (scroll-other-window '-))
                       ("a" . (beginning-of-buffer-other-window 0))
                       ("e" . (end-of-buffer-other-window 0))))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be stated anywhere explicitly, but I found that `C-g' quits the repeat mode.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I use.  I like it because you don't have to specify the repeating key.

```
(require 'repeat)
(defun make-repeatable-command (cmd)
  "Returns a new command that is a repeatable version of CMD.
The new command is named CMD-repeat.  CMD should be a quoted
command.

This allows you to bind the command to a compound keystroke and
repeat it with just the final key.  For example:

  (global-set-key (kbd \"C-c a\") (make-repeatable-command 'foo))

will create a new command called foo-repeat.  Typing C-c a will
just invoke foo.  Typing C-c a a a will invoke foo three times,
and so on."
  (fset (intern (concat (symbol-name cmd) "-repeat"))
        `(lambda ,(help-function-arglist cmd) ;; arg list
           ,(format "A repeatable version of `%s'." (symbol-name cmd)) ;; doc string
           ,(interactive-form cmd) ;; interactive form
           ;; see also repeat-message-function
           (setq last-repeatable-command ',cmd)
           (repeat nil)))
  (intern (concat (symbol-name cmd) "-repeat")))
```

Comment: I like this a lot, but note that CMD *must* already be loaded (autoloading is insufficient), otherwise the arglist and interactive-form interrogations will fail. (Actually the latter *would* trigger autoloading, but the arglist which preceeds it will be wrong).

Answer (score 2):

You want your `function-foo` to use `set-temporary-overlay-map`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @juanleon suggested, which uses `set-temporary-overlay-map`, here is an alternative that I use quite a bit.  It uses standard library `repeat.el`.

```
;; This function builds a repeatable version of its argument COMMAND.
(defun repeat-command (command)
  "Repeat COMMAND."
 (interactive)
 (let ((repeat-previous-repeated-command  command)
       (last-repeatable-command           'repeat))
   (repeat nil)))
```

Use that to define different repeatable commands.  E.g.,

```
(defun backward-char-repeat ()
  "Like `backward-char', but repeatable even on a prefix key."
  (interactive)
  (repeat-command 'backward-char))
```

Then bind such a command to a key with a repeatable suffix, e.g., `C-c =` (for `C-c = = = =`...)

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20535110/729907) for more information.