# Use key as both prefix and command

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to know how to use a key as both a prefix for other keys and a command itself.

1. I can sorta do this with `key-chord.el`, by binding the key chords to the commands following the first key but it has several issues

   - Can only be used with alphanumeric keys
   - Isn't real since I have to hit the keys quickly before they timeout
2. Some packages such as `easy-kill` and `expand-region` support this functionality, but they have complex codebases, and my lisp skills aren't spectacular...

How would I manage to do this? I'd really like `<menu>` to be bound to `evil-ex`, but I'd like to also bind `<menu>` as a prefix for all movements (like arrow-keys) that sets the mark like a chordless `cua-selection-mode`.

Since evil-ex isn't followed by movements and no movement self inserts, this would be a perfect use-case. `<menu>` is perfect because it's right next to the arrow keys and other motions keys (eg. end, home etc.) and it's unmodified.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... you want to run a command when you type `<menu>`, but if you type a movement command next you want to... undo the previous command and do something different instead???

Comment: Or are you saying that `evil-ex` (what is it, please?) itself *requires* additional keystrokes, so you can safely wait for the subsequent key (movement or non-movement) before deciding which function to call?

Comment: This thread contains a similar concept:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026083/how-to-use-escape-conditionally-as-a-modifier-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want something like [smartrep](https://github.com/myuhe/smartrep.el) which enables specifying a key as a common prefix for several commands.  The only thing you'll be missing out-of-the-box is binding a command to the common prefix key, so you'll need to get your hands dirty with `smartrep` internals a bit. The function you're after is

```
(smartrep-read-event-loop
  '((KEY1 command)
    (KEY2 command)
    ...))
```

Here's a piece of code that may get you started:

```lisp
(defun my-command-with-prefix ()
  (interactive)

  (invoke-prefix-command)

  (initialize-event-loop)

  ;; The form
  ;;
  ;;   (condition-case ERR FORM (quit QUIT-HANDLER))
  ;;
  ;; is there to catch C-g key presses and make sure that
  ;; finalization code is run.
  (condition-case e
      (smartrep-read-event-loop
       '(("a" . command1)
         ("b" . command2)
         ("c" . command3)))

    (quit nil))

  ;; finalize loop
  (finalize-event-loop))
```

The snippet above is essentially a distilled version of code found [here](https://github.com/masaaki1001/.emacs.d/blob/master/config/init-smartrep.el).

Answer (score 5):

If I understand what you want, I'd suggest that it is better to forget about timers and waiting a slight delay (i.e., to distinguish the intention of `<menu>` as a command from its use as a prefix key).

The approach I recommend, and use quite a bit, is to define a prefix key (in your case, e.g., `<menu>`), and then put the command that you were thinking of using for `<menu>` on `<menu> <menu>`.  That's as quick as hitting `<menu>` once and trying to rely on some tiny delay etc.

And it allows the command you think of as being on `<menu>` (really it is on `<menu> <menu>`) to be ***repeatable***.

I *typically* make such a command repeatable, so that `<menu> <menu> <menu>` repeats the command once, `<menu> <menu> <menu> <menu>` repeats it twice, and so on.  IOW, I tend to use this trick for commands that I really want to repeat easily, by just holding down a key.

Here's a simple example, from a suggestion I made more generally to `emacs-devel@gnu.org` back in 2009, [***HERE***](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2009-08/msg01153.html).  In that mailing-list message, if you scroll down to #9 you will see the proposal to use such keys,  #12 shows this same example, and #15 addresses your question directly.  The thread title is "*have cake will eat,eat cake will have - krazy key koncept kontroversy*", and its subject is ***exactly the question you raised***.

---

```
;; This function builds a repeatable version of its argument COMMAND.
(defun repeat-command (command)
  "Repeat COMMAND."
 (interactive)
 (let ((repeat-previous-repeated-command  command)
       (last-repeatable-command           'repeat))
   (repeat nil)))

Here is how you could then define `C-x', which is already a prefix
key, as also a repeatable key for an action command, in this case,
`backward-char':

(defun backward-char-repeat ()
  "Like `backward-char', but repeatable even on a prefix key."
  (interactive)
  (repeat-command 'backward-char))

(define-key ctl-x-map "\C-x" 'backward-char-repeat)

Now just holding down `C-x' invokes `backward-char' repeatedly - once
you've gotten past the first `C-x' (the prefix).
```

As I say, I've long used this technique to be able to (a) have "repeating prefix keys" and (b) still have other keys defined on them.

Comment: Prefix maps are a fantastic way to open up keybinding possibilities. Adding the repeating command function to the original command gives you the best of both worlds - quick access to the original command, plus a whole new set of unbound keys in the keymap to play with.

Comment: @Tyler -- I think so too.  I use this "trick" all the time, in fact.  A typical use is in [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus), where I have lots of bookmarking commands on the same prefix key (e.g., `C-x p`) but I have various types of bookmark-cycling commands on repeatable keys on that map (`e.g., `C-x p down`, `C-x p right`).

Comment: Thanks, I found this really useful (I also launch a lot of commands off of `<C-menu> <something>`.) Now I can repeat them!

Comment: Sure! (I didn't know that I could).