# key chords in isearch

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I really love [`key-chord.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/key-chord.el). It's become an integral part of my workflow, but sometimes I wish I could have them in the minibuffer (for things like evil-search). Specifically, I'd like `jj` to exit out of `evil-search` and move down a line. Is this possible?

I know I can hack together a command that acts as both a prefix and a command (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534733/use-key-as-both-prefix-and-command/20538075?noredirect=1)), so I could bind `j` to a self inserting command, and `jj` to my special command. How would I be able to break the event loop after a specified idle time? I do type `jj` once in a blue moon, and I'd still like the flexibility of a timeout.

Is there any other way which I am unaware of to achieve what I want?

EDIT:

Origionally, this question was about the minibuffer in general. `key-chord.el` seems to work fine with `minibuffer-local-map`. It does not, however, work with `isearch-mode-map`. Binding a command to a single regular key like `j` does work in isearch. This is what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: You didn't even link `key-chord.el` to its source code (I've edited the post to do that now). Why don't you explain what the problem is, in terms of the code?  Why doesn't it do what you want, when in the minibuffer? Have you tried using `key-chord-define` with the minibuffer keymaps?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. The problem seems to be specific to `isearch-mode-map`. Nothing happens. I'm not sure how to say that in terms of the code.

Comment: +1 for alerting me to the existence of `key-chord.el`, which seems very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution which manually reproduces the behaviour of key-chord.el.

```lisp
(defun isearch-exit-chord-worker (&optional arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (execute-kbd-macro (kbd "<backspace> <return>")))

(defun isearch-exit-chord (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (isearch-printing-char)
  (unless (fboundp 'smartrep-read-event-loop)
    (require 'smartrep))
  (run-at-time 0.3 nil 'keyboard-quit)
  (condition-case e
    (smartrep-read-event-loop
      '(("j" . isearch-exit-chord-worker)
         ("k" . isearch-exit-chord-worker)))
    (quit nil)))

;; example bindings
(define-key isearch-mode-map "j" 'isearch-exit-chord)
(define-key isearch-mode-map "k" 'isearch-exit-chord)
```

This approach actually has several advantages over `key-chord.el`.

- It does not use an input method, so you can use a different input method in conjunction with this.
- The first character is shown immediately, and retracted if it is incorrect, while `key-chord.el` only shows it after a delay.

Comment: How do you enable it?  I want this functionality rather badly.

Comment: `(define-key isearch-mode-map "j" 'isearch-exit-chord)
(define-key isearch-mode-map "k" 'isearch-exit-chord)` please upvote if you found this useful.

Comment: Awesome, thanks much.  I would add that to your answer for completeness sake.

Comment: Thanks. Tip: If you want, you can edit any answer yourself if you think it needs improvement. (For example, if I were not around, you could edit it yourself.)

Answer (score 2):

I have found this to be useful:

```
(defun isearch-enable-key-chord ()
  (key-chord-mode 1)
  (key-chord-define isearch-mode-map "jj" 'isearch-cancel))
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook 'isearch-enable-key-chord)
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me.