# exit Emacs evil operator mode with "jk" keychord

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I want to exit evil-mode's operator pending state when I press "jk" in quick succession.

For example, If I press `d`, and then `jk`, nothing should be deleted and Emacs should be in normal mode.

I tried using [key-chord.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord) to exit the operator mode like so, but it didn't work.

```
(key-chord-define evil-operator-state-map "jk" 'evil-force-normal-state)
```

A similar question was how to exit isearch with "jk": [key chords in isearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926215).  I think the solution might require a similar approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little hacky as it relies on `<down>` being bound to the same as `j`, but it's the best I can do with my current evil-knowledge. It should work properly in all cases, including repeats.

```
(define-key evil-operator-state-map "j" 'evil-operator-state-j)

(evil-define-command evil-operator-state-j ()   (save-excursion
    (let ((evt (read-event "Press k to exit operator state" nil 0.5)))
      (if (and (integerp evt) (char-equal evt ?k))
          (keyboard-quit)
        ;; assume <down> is bound to the same as j:
        (let* ((operator-string (substring (this-command-keys) 0 -1)) ; get the keys used to invoke the operator
               (new-macro (kbd (concat operator-string " <down>"))))  ; add " <down>" to the end instead of "j"
          (evil-force-normal-state)
          (execute-kbd-macro new-macro)
          (when (not (null evt))
            (push evt unread-command-events))))))) ; process any other key pressed within 0.5 seconds
```

If you find a bug or have any questions about how it works, just ask. :)

Comment: Works, found one bug.  If you press d (or similar command) and then j quickly enough, nothing happens, it simply exits.

Comment: @Joes Hmmm, for me, `dj` always deletes 2 lines after 0.5 seconds, even with virtually simultaneous key presses. Unfortunately I don't think elisp will be able to 'speed up' this solution any more. Out of curiousity, are you running emacs in a terminal or in 'GUI mode'?

Comment: Not a big deal, it works plenty well enough in practice.  The key presses to toggle the bug have to practically simultaneous.  I'm using GUI mode.