# Using 2 consecutive control key in Emacs

Tags: emacs, set, key

I recently using "increment-number-at-point"(http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IncrementNumber) and  assigned it as following.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-+") 'increment-number-at-point)
```

I think executing "C-c C-+" twice means this.

```
            |--------------------------------------------------------------->time
control key |<---------pressed---------> <---------pressed---------> 
c key       | <-pressed->                 <-pressed->                 
+ key       |               <-pressed->                 <-pressed->
```

Now the command was executed twice. It takes me several times. So I want to make this work as following.

```
            |--------------------------------------------------------------->time
control key |<----------------pressed----------------->
c key       | <-pressed->
+ key       |             <-pressed-><-pressed->
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: See also [this closely related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20534733/729907).

Comment: Thanks you very much. I don't know the mechanism, but I could do it with @Drew's "repeat-command". Thanks a lot.